# Error while SVN commit in eclipse

Tags: svn

This was happen first time,

When I commit my one of the file through eclipse it's giving below error while commit.
Please advise. What do we mean by "out of date" error.

[image]

---

Update:

See below image, I am just clicking on commit. Nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating?

Comment: What I need to update in this case? File is already updated and display as changed in team synchronization.

Comment: "Update" is a first class Subversion operation. SVN clients normally offer it labelled as such. (But it's weird because it also says "Merge conflict".) Have you clicked the "Details >>" button?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I am just clicking on commit. I didn't do any thing else. See my updated image in question. Nothing found like detail even. By the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your original screenshot features a big fat "Details >>" button and your second screenshot features an "Update" item. Sorry but I cannot click on them for you.

Comment: Yup helpful, When I click on "Update" it modified my current version with merging the version at source safe. as well added 3 new files with same name included .mine and some other files. What I did is, I copied text of my current file and keep it to safe place. Then click on update. That modified my current file poorly (I don't know what it did) but once I paste back my actual code from my safe place and clicked on commit. That resolved this issue. But really what happen at mid part when I click update, it still unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file named 'Redundant Control System.xml' has a newer version in the repository than the one your working copy is based on (called the BASE).  Subversion will not allow you to commit a file with a BASE different from the last modified version for the file you're committing in the repository.

You should run an update, deal with any merges or conflicts that result, and attempt your commit again.

This section of the svnbook covers this:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit